# How apply src from object when using video-js

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

I am having hard time using video-player for streaming m3u8 videos
Below works but I want to use src from object

```html
<video
            id="my-video"
            class="video-js"
            autoplay
            preload="auto"
            data-setup="{}"
        >
            <source type="application/x-mpegURL"
            src=https://multiplatform-f.akamaihd.net/i/multi/will/bunny/big_buck_bunny_,640x360_400,640x360_700,640x360_1000,950x540_1500,.f4v.csmil/master.m3u8
            />
        </video>
```

Instead of using hard coded src, I am trying to get src from an object that looks like this :

```js
    post: [{post_no:1,post_author:"Mercy", url:"http://demo.unified-streaming.com/video/tears-of-steel/tears-of-steel.ism/.m3u8",},],
```

So I thought I could do something like this which none of them worked

#### idea 1

```html
<video
            id="my-video"
            class="video-js"
            controls
            autoplay
            preload="auto"
            data-setup="{}"
        >
            <source type="application/x-mpegURL"
            :src="post.url"
            />
        </video>
```

#### idea 2

```js
playerOptions: {
                    preload: "auto",
                    autoplay: true,
                    muted: true,
                    loop: true,
                    aspectRatio: "4:3",
                    sources: [
                        {
                            type: "application/x-mpegURL",
                            src: this.post.url,
                        },
                    ],
                },
```

Sadly, none of them worked. Is there any way I can do?

Comment: Post is an array so do it like post[0].url

Comment: I tried that , but unfortunately it did not work for me ;~;

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out.
Instead of using method, using created() solved this problem.
So my source code is like this :

```js
    created() {
            this.playerOptions = {
                preload: "auto",
                autoplay: true,
                muted: true,
                loop: true,
                aspectRatio: "4:3",
                sources: [
                    {
                        type: "application/x-mpegURL",
                        src: this.post.url,
                    },
                ],
            };
        },
```